# Makefile Cygwin: mkdir, "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Tags: makefile, cygwin, mkdir

Running the following `Makefile` gives an error message

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

This is because the makefile calls `mkdir` which is a windows command instead of `mkdir` from Cygwin. Even though I put cygwin path first in the environment variable, it still calls the windows `mkdir` instead of the Cygwin one. One quick way to fix is to use `mkdir.exe`. Then the Cygwin one is called. I am looking for a method to call the correct one without changing the `Makefile` is there any way to tell `Makefile` which one it should call. Something in the settings?

```
all:
    echo "make started"
    mkdir -p test/tmp
    echo "make ended"
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\New_folder>make
echo "make started"
"make started"
mkdir -p test/tmp
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
make: *** [all] Error 1

C:\Users\me\Desktop\New_folder>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a method to call the correct one without changing the `Makefile` is there any way to tell `Makefile` which one it should call. Something in the settings?

It's unclear which setting you're referring to, but the root of the issue is the shell the Makefile is using.  It looks like it's getting cmd.exe in your case, so unqualified "mkdir" triggers its builtin.  No path search is performed.

You could try to work around that by directing `make` to use a different shell, something like this:

```
make SHELL=\path\to\cygwin\bash.exe
```

or you could launch `make` from a `bash` shell in the first place.

Be aware, however, that even if that works, this may not be the last issue you encounter.  Makefiles not built with Windows specifically in mind -- which is most of them -- cannot often adapt to the quite different Windows environment.  I've had more luck with MinGW in this area, and then with Automake-based makefiles, but it has nevertheless required some special accommodation in makefile sources and in programming-language sources.